# Версия приложения

Tags: android

Как вывести на экран версию приложения в Android Studio?
Мне нужен номер сборки для отображения в пользовательском интерфейсе.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Версию можно получить так:

```
try {
    PackageInfo pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    String version = pInfo.versionName;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

и номер версии:

```
int verCode = pInfo.versionCode;
```

Если вы используете градл, то можно так получить версию:

```
int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
```

но нужно не забыть указать в градле эту информацию:

```
defaultConfig {
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

### update

для отображения в textView:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
myTextView.setText(versionName );
```

Comment: Как это отобразить в TextView?

Comment: @Unknown, обновил ответ